# How can I manually change my dropbox folder location when it won't show in the chooser

Tags: macos, dropbox

When trying to choose a dropbox folder location, the folder I want to use is not visible in the file chooser dialog. I can see the folder in finder and terminal. I recently copied my home folder to a new disk but Dropbox has kept the original path to `Users/me/dropbox`

Has anyone done this manually? Is it enough to change `~/.dropbox/info.json`?

folder permissions are :

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 86 myusername  staff  2924 29 Jun 19:43 foldername
```

ls -le:

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 86 myname  staff  2924 29 Jun 19:43 foldername
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

Comment: Why won't it show in the chooser? Is it a hidden folder?

Comment: What are the permissions on the new folder?

Comment: Its not a hidden folder. I've updated the question with the permissions.

Comment: Can you do ls -le to show the folder permissions - as there is an @ in your output there are also extended attributes